# torch.to(device) Not in effect

Tags: pytorch

```
    token_embeddings.to(device)
    print(device)
    print(token_embeddings.device)
```

cuda:0
cpu

I use 'torch.to(device)', but it is not in effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix input and parameter tensors are not at the same device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521735/how-to-fix-input-and-parameter-tensors-are-not-at-the-same-device)

Answer (score 0):

`.to()` is not an in-place operation. So you need to do:

```
token_embeddings = token_embeddings.to(device)
```